# iOS: background process and singleton

Tags: ios, core-data, singleton, uibackgroundtask

In my app I should populate a core data DB and I want do it also in background

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]) { //Check if our iOS version supports multitasking I.E iOS 4
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) { //Check if device supports mulitasking
            UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication]; //Get the shared application instance

            __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task; //Create a task object

            background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^ {
                [application endBackgroundTask: background_task]; //Tell the system that we are done with the tasks
                background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; //Set the task to be invalid

                //System will be shutting down the app at any point in time now
            }];

            //Background tasks require you to use asyncrous tasks

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                //Perform your tasks that your application requires

                DBSync *sync = [DBSync sharedInstance];

                [sync startDownloadDataandUpdateDB];

                [application endBackgroundTask: background_task]; //End the task so the system knows that you are done with what you need to perform
                background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; //Invalidate the background_task
            });
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that the method "startDownloadDataandUpdateDB" is called, but this method call other method in DBSync but these others methods don't work, I don't understand

Comment: You'll need to be specific about what the symptoms of "don't work" are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is not really good practice to make network calls in that method.

[The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground)  states that you have approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return.

You might want to take a look to beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler

Comment: yes ok, but if I call it in '- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' the method not call the other methods internal at DBSync